# Efficiency of fopen() with 'a' option in PHP

Tags: php, performance, fopen, fwrite

If I write `fopen($myfile, 'a')`, and `$myfile` is a very large file,  will the server have to read the entire file in order to return the pointer to the end of the file? Or does it quickly find the pointer to the end of the file and then return that?

On a related note, when I then use `fwrite()` I assume it doesn't overwrite the whole file, right? It just appends stuff?

I'm basically trying to figure out whether `fopen()` with the `'a'` option, and `fwrite()` are O(1) or O(n), where n is the length of the prexisting file.

Comment: The OS positions the file pointer for writing right at the end. It does not need to read over the existing content.

Answer (score 4):

The actual complexity depends on the complexity of the underlying filesystem, but PHP itself will not loop or read through the entire file, it will seek to the end and start writing from there. When opening a file in append more, it will not be erased by fwrite (you could easily try this to see how it works).

Comment: Thanks Matti. When I asked about fwrite() I really meant to ask if it rewrites the entire file instead of just writing stuff at the storage memory corresponding to the end of the file. I was again trying to get an idea about how efficient fwrite() is. But I think it's pretty clear now that it does not rewrite everything. Thanks again for your helpful and very quick response!

Answer (score 3):

(Related)
Note that you can also use `file_put_contents` instead of `fopen/fwrite/fclose` for appending to files - if you are that much concerned about speed:

```
file_put_contents($filename, $data, FILE_APPEND);
```

This is a bit more atomic, and does not necessitate locking.

Answer (score 1):

No, `fopen` does not need to read the whole file just to jump to the end. A simple seek is all that is needed.